# .match specific pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I am trying to match a specific pattern using `.match()` method but I'm a bit confused. I have a string that looks something like this.

```
SomeError on example.com/register/
[u'Some Error Message Here, That we want to parse'].

Some more text here
Some more text here
```

I'm trying to parse out `Some Error Message Here, That we want to parse` text from the above string. the current `regex` that I am using is :

```
response.match(/.*[u'(.*).*']/)
```

which gives me:

```
[u'Some Error Message Here, That we want to parse.'
```

but I also want to eliminate `[u'` and `'` part so that result looks something like this:

```
Some Error Message Here, That we want to parse
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to escape brackets (`[` and `]`) :

```
response.match(/.*\[u'(.*).*'\]/)
```

Comment: thanks for your response @Samuel, but using the above regex is returning `[u'Invalid value debug for email. Please try again later or report the problem to us.'],Invalid value debug for email. Please try again later or report the problem to us.`. I don't understand why.

Comment: Yes match return an array with first element the string matched and the other elements are those captured by the parentheses (`(`, `)`).

Comment: ohh i see so `response.match(/.*\[u'(.*).*'\]/)[1]` this should do the trick i guess. Thanks ! :)

Comment: In your case, since you want what is after the `[u'`, you want what is captured in the first group, so it is `response.match(/.*\[u'(.*).*'\]/)[1]` (and not index 0 where it get your whole pattern).

Answer (score 2):

Actually your regex is right, except for the fact that the `[ ]` braces should be escaped.

The `match` function gives you an array of matches, you just have to go get the right one :

```
var str="SomeError on example.com/register/\n[u'Some Error Message Here, That we want to parse'].\n\nSome more text here\nSome more text here";

var n = str.match(/.*\[u'(.*).*'\]/);

​alert(n[1]);​ // Prints "Some Error Message Here, That we want to parse"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to escape square brackets.

`match` returns an array of matches, so, value wrapped in round brackets will be at index 1 of this array.

```
response.match(/.*\[u'(.*)'\]/)[1]
```

Or you can try

```
/.*\[u'(.*)'\]/.exec(response)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This shoudl do it. Your regex is wrong btw... (you forgot to escape the `[` and `]`

```
<html>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var response= "[u'Some Error Message Here, That we want to parse'].";

            if(response.match(/^.*\[u'.*'\].*$/)){
                var message = response.replace(/^.*\[u'/, '');
                var message = message.replace(/\'].*$/, '');
                document.write(message);
            } 
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```